# Super Admin can't edit channel content

Tags: channel-entries, control-panel, super-admin

I have a user setup as a Super Admin. There is one single channel entry that she cannot edit. Her system locks up when she attempts to edit it. She can edit anything else on the site but this one entry, no.

Any ideas of what to look at to figure this one out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by lock up, you mean WSOD (white screen of death), the issue is usually a database write error. If you can open that channel entry, do it. Usually, it's a WYGWAM field. If you have one in their, click on the `source` button, and copy and paste the WYGWAM source to a notepad. Then, empty that field, and save the entry. Then, reopen it, click `source`, and paste the source back in and save it.

Rinse and repeat for each field in the entry.

Comment: Not really sure if she gets that, the system just kind of locks up with the page showing. It is just unresponsive.

Comment: Can you be clear on what you mean by system? Is this an OS level lockup? Browser lockup? TBH, if the actual computer is locking up, and it's not just a page failing to render, then it's her computer, not EE, and isn't really an EE related question.

Comment: Browser, the page just becomes unresponsive. doesn't happen on other entries. Must be EE.

Comment: Is it reproducible on another browser? Is it reproducible on another machine?

Comment: Yes. She has a MacBook running Chrome and it also occurs under her user on my Windows machine using Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: Actually, just retried and I'm able to edit on my Windows machine in Chrome using her account.

Comment: Try it on a bunch of different machines / OS's / browsers. See if you can really reduce your error positive to specific environments.

Comment: Make sure to check the javascript console to make sure there isn't anything clashing with each other. Also might want to clear the EE cache.

Comment: Seems that it was the Mac causing the issues, after all. Any objections to a deletion here?

Comment: Well, I did suggest you try different machines to see if it was isolated to one machines, so I wouldn't mind the points :P your call, mang.